# IE doesn't recognize JQuery content-loading

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, hide, show

I'm using a JQuery script to load, hide and show content on a page, with a gif file that's visible to the user while the content loads on the page. This works in Safari and Firefox but not on IE. The user can see the content loading.

Thanks for any suggestion on how to resolve this.

The JQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("#content-loading").show();
$("#block_a").hide();
  $(window).load(function() {
    $("#block_a").show();
    $("#content-loading").hide();
  })
})
</script>
```

The div containing the gif:

```
<div id="content-loading">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be that you're using `$(document).ready` to  show the content-loading gif and hide the block_a. Try putting this in a CSS stylesheet at the top of your page:

`#block_a { display:none; }`

That will hide the block immediately.

Answer (score 0):

You are hiding the content in the `ready` event, which occurs when the entire document is loaded. Also Internet Explorer doesn't have any `DOMContentLoaded` event, so it occurs slightly later there as jQuery has to use the `readyStateChange` event instead.

You should hide the content using CSS instead, that way it's hidden already when it comes into existance:

```
<style type="text/css">
#block_a { display: none; }
</style>
```

You can still use the jQuery `show` method to show the content from the `load` event.